# Why does echo of an environment variable do not work, but printenv does, inside a docker?

Tags: bash, docker

My system: Visual studio code dev container, on Windows 10.

I try to use environment variables inside my docker container.

A file `xyz.env` holds my environment variables

```
TOKEN=12345

PROJECT_ID_1=8888
PROJECT_ID_2=9999

FOLDER=./tmp
```

I have a shell script `script.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/sh

BASEDIR=$(dirname $0)

docker run --rm \
    --env-file $BASEDIR/xyz.env \
    alpine:latest \
    printenv && echo "$HOSTNAME" && echo "$FOLDER" && echo "--- END ---"
```

When I call `script.sh` the `output` is

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=4ddcb55c018f
TOKEN=12345
PROJECT_ID_1=8888
PROJECT_ID_2=9999
FOLDER=./tmp
HOME=/root
072bf158678c

--- END ---
```

PATH, HOSTNAME, HOME is there already (I don't mind)

TOKEN, PROJECT_ID_1, PROJECT_ID_2 and FOLDER are there, when I print them via `printenv`.

- When I use e.g. `echo $FOLDER` it is NOT there!? -> See empty line
- When I use e.g. `echo $HOSTNAME` it is there, but with an different value!? -> See line before "end".

So how I can use the ENV variable from my file inside the docker container?

I have the same behavior when I run the docker run directly (without a script), like

```sh
docker run --rm \
    --env-file scripts/xyz.env \
    alpine:latest \
    printenv && echo "$HOSTNAME" && echo "$FOLDER" && echo "--- END ---"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, you are using variables from your host machine while running your command, as you are doing for `$BASEDIR`. As they don't exist on your host, your command looks like the following:

```sh
docker run --rm \
    --env-file scripts/xyz.env \
    alpine:latest \
    printenv && echo "" && echo "" && echo "--- END ---"
```

By escaping the dollar sign with `\`, the container should run the right command using its own env vars:

```sh
docker run --rm \
    --env-file $BASEDIR/xyz.env \
    alpine:latest \
    printenv && echo "\$HOSTNAME" && echo "\$FOLDER" && echo "--- END ---"
```

But this still won't work because of the `&&`: the container will run `printenv`, then your host will run the `echo` commands.
You should run all of those as a single command:

```sh
docker run --rm \
    --env-file $BASEDIR/xyz.env \
    alpine:latest \
    /bin/sh -c 'printenv && echo "$HOSTNAME" && echo "$FOLDER" && echo "--- END ---"'
```

> No need for escaping here as the commands are passed as a string with single quote, with no variable expansion from your host.

Comment: Thanks! OMG I forgot the `/bin/ash -c` behind my docker image. Oh soooo simple